# Liquibase rename column with spaces in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

I try to rename a column with spaces in SQL server as below,

```
<renameColumn catalogName="SB_IFU" schemaName="dbo" tableName="tblConsent" oldColumnName="Consent_Date of Expiry" newColumnName="Consent_Date_of_Expiry"/>
```

however, there is an error that Liquibase cannot find that column in DB,

[image: Liquibase]

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: try `oldColumnName="'Consent_Date of Expiry'"` or `oldColumnName="\"Consent_Date of Expiry\""`

Comment: On a more general note - when asking questions on coding topics, it is frequently better to include the actual text of a message rather than a screenshot of text.